# Field defines a relation with model 'Division', which is either not installed, or is abstract. Django

Tags: python, django

Всем добрый день!
У меня выдаётся ошибка:

> I have Error: polls.Choice.division_names: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Division', which is either not installed, or is abstract

**models.py**

```
class Division(models.Model):
    division_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'db'
        db_table = "divisions"
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: `class Division(models.Model):
    division_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'db'
        db_table = "divisions"`

Comment: есть какая то модель которая имеет отношение(ForeginKey и тд) к Division? Ну и makemigrations&&migrate ты делал?